# How to figure out what place my item is in, in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I have a set of children items that I have ordered in a way that I want them to show on the website. What I would like to know is, is there a way to figure out what place my item is in other than getting a list of all of the items and rendering them that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you want linq

Comment: Do you mean given 1 item of a set, see where in the set it is? The set having come from a ChildList, eg .Children or .GetChildren()...?

Comment: actually the item is set in the datasource for the rendering

Comment: so I'm not using .children or get children, the list is rendered through the presentation details (each item has a corresponding view)

Comment: So if you have 5 child items, you have 5 views added each with a datasource set to each item? Sounds tedious, why not use a repeater to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
int position = item.Parent.GetChildren().IndexOf(item.ID);
```

This will give you the index position of an item in its parent's children collection.